# Why can't I enable Firmware Protection?

Tags: windows-11

I have a 12900K CPU and an MSI PRO Z960-A motherboard which should cover all the requirements of Firmware Protection on the latest Windows 11. For some reason I cannot enable that security feature while everything else is working without any problem. I tried enabling it using the Local Group Policy Editor and restarting and although there it appears to be enabled, it is still disabled in Core Isolation page of the security settings. I tried reparing with dism and other Windows diagnostic tools including resetting the Windows installation. I even updated all the drivers to the latest version but that made no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Attempting to activate Core Isolation should tell you the reason it cannot be activated. Is that not happening?

Comment: As I said "...everything else is working..." which means that all the other security features including core isolation are enabled and working except for Firmware Protection.